# Reupload Issue with Intuit Sync Manager sync failed SalesReceipt

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, ipp-qbd-sync

I am facing some issues in Syncing SalesReceipt to Intuit QuickBooks desktop edition the actual scenario is like,

I have exported  a Intuit QuickBooks SalesRecepit to Intuit QuickBooks Cloud and run the QuickBooks Sync Manager to upload exported SalesReceipt to QuickBooks desktop.

Sync Manager attempted to upload the  SalesReceipt to QuickBooks desktop and failed to upload (i.e.Sync Manager tried to Sync SalesReceipt)

Now I need to clear that SalesReceipt record from Intuit QuickBooks Cloud to reexport that record to QuickBooks Cloud or How can I find that Sync Manager Has attepted to upload that record and failed to upload for some reasons so that I can identify such records to reexport into QuickBooks .

Please suggest your views and suggesions , need help as soon as possible.

Thanks & Regards,

Reshma D.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SyncStatus API to determine whether or not a record successfully synced:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/syncstatus

If it hasn't synced, you can then re-send it / delete the old object / update it.

The documentation page linked above has extensive documentation about the different error codes and states an object can be in.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by executing a query and setting ErroredObjectsOnly=true.

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0015_Retrieving_Objects#Objects_in_Error_State

If the entity is in error state, you can query(in this case, for SalesReceipt) for the specific reason using the SyncStatus API and setting ErroredObjectsOnly=true.

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncStatus

From there, you will need to delete or revert the object in error state, depending on if a sync has occurred.

Delete (sync has not occurred):

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/Deleting_an_Object

If a successful sync did occur with the entity at least once, but then an Update pushed it into error state, you will need to do a Revert:

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/Reverting_an_Object

Hope it will be useful.

Thanks